# What Pokémon are available in limited quantities?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

Seeing as Pokémon that previously were exclusive to gifts or stationary encounters, like the starters, are now freely available in the wild, are there any left that you can only get in limited quantities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can remember, ignoring trading, Mystery Gift, or transferring from Pokémon GO, there are only two Pokémon that are limited in quantity. These are:

- Mewtwo
- Persian/Arcanine in Vermillion City (depending on your version)

Legendary Birds, Snorlax, and starters can all be found in the wild. Version exclusives from the other game other than the gift Persian/Arcanine can't be found at all in a given game, so they aren't on this list.

I may have forgotten one but I think this list is complete in the context of a single game.

Comment: Can the fossils be found in the wild?

Comment: @inakilbss Fossils can be infinitely farmed in Cerulean Cave at three locations and the 2 (next to the big crystal in the center) and B1 floors (two locations - one near the ladder and one near Mewtwo)